# keyup event not triggering from textarea

Tags: javascript, events, keyup

I'm trying to make a function that gets triggered every time a user inputs text into a textarea (in order to make a character counter). The textarea is:

```
     <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-12 col-form-label align-self-center">
        <label for="enquiry">What sort of cuisine are you interested in? Do you have any dietary requirements?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 align-self-center">
        <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="enquiry" rows="4" value="test"> </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And then this is the javascript - currently the function is just a console.log to show me if it's being triggered, but it's not showing up:

```
const enquiryInput = document.getElementById("enquiry");
enquiryInput.addEventListener("keyup", enquiryCount);

function enquiryCount() {
    console.log("enquiry function being triggered");
};
```

What am I doing wrong?? I have been pulling my hair out for an hour

Comment: I dropped your code into a codepen, and it works for me: https://codepen.io/kshetline/pen/oNWgvjm?editors=1111

Comment: Maybe you accidentally have reused the id "enquiry", so there's more than one element matching that id?

Comment: Oh that makes it even more mysterious! I've definitely not reused that id, but I'll try and dig through to work out what I've done somewhere else to break it. Thanks kshetline, I should've tried it in a codepen. Now to work out what is going on 

Comment: @GordonMaloney something may be messing with the textarea on the page. Maybe some 3th party textarea wrapper, or some other JS code related to keyup events on the document.